# Ruby sort method acts strangely when negative integers involved

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

Given the following string:

```
numbers =  "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"
```

I want to get this in numerical order. This is the code I am using

```
numbers.split(' ').sort
```

However, this is returning the following:

```
["-214", "-3", "-6", "-64", "0", "1", "29", "4", "4", "5", "54", "542", "6"]
```

Why is sort behaving this way. Ideally the array should have -214 as the first integer and 542 as the second. How can I achieve this?

Desired output:

["-214", "-64", "-6", "-3", "0", "1", "4", "4", "5", "6", "26", "54", "542"]

Comment: Those aren't integers.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby's `sort` defaults to, when operating on strings, sorting in lexicographical order, as it has done here. If you want to sort by numerical order, you want to do something like:

```
numbers.split.sort_by(&:to_i)
```

Comment: `split` by default splits on whitespace so only `split` and not `split(' ')` is required.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for you.

numbers.map{|v| v.to_i}.sort{|a,b| a <=> b}